# How to make the progress bar work in synchronization with the function for javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have made function test automation tool for our app.

But when I made the progress bar work in synchronization with the stage, I got the problem.

I want to make the progress bar working according to function execution Synchronously.

However, my code doesn't work as I intended.

Here is my code. The test code.

moveBar() means that just move progress bar's width +1.

```js
function Automation(){
//Init Data
resultList="";
total=44;
//Process
Create();moveBar();
start();moveBar();
Activate3();moveBar();
RoadManager();moveBar();
Test1();moveBar();
False1();moveBar();
False2();moveBar();
False3();moveBar();
False4();moveBar();
False5();moveBar();
False6();moveBar();
Activate4();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
Activate5();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
functionName();moveBar();
end();moveBar();
onButton("btn");
onButton("btn2");
onButton("btn3");
}
```

How to solve this problem? I want to make beautiful UI.

Thanks you. I'm waiting for you.

Comment: while javascrpit code is running, updates to rendered output won't be shown

Comment: Thanks you for comment.